# DSpace OAI-PMH harvesting metadata export

Tags: metadata, dspace, ieee, oai

I wish to expose additional metadata via OAI-PMH in my DSpace instance.  I have added a new metadata schema "lrmi" and also added some metadata fields. Through the submission forms I have been able to use the fields in my lrmi schema. However, I seem unable to expose these fields in the DSpace OAI-PMH interface, as it only exposes fields from the dc schema. How can custom fields from a new schema be exposed in the OAI-PMH interface? The same problem occurs with "IEEE-LOM" schema also. I think the question has enough relevance for this forum but not sure why this was closed from one of my earlier posts.

Comment: I am glad that you re-posted the question.  From a DSpace perspective, this is an appropriate question.

Comment: I took a look at my OAI repository, and I confirmed that my custom metadata schema is present.  Have you created a custom XSLT crosswalk that attempts to access these fields?

Comment: While waiting for a more complete answer from someone with a deeper knowledge of this topic than me, you might want to take a look a those files: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/master/dspace/config/crosswalks/oai/metadataFormats. As far as I know, they contain the XLS transformation defining your OAI output, for each possible prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about your question, made a few more researches and tests. Turns out that editing [those files](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/tree/master/dspace/config/crosswalks/oai/metadataFormats) I mentioned in an earlier comment will indeed do what you're trying to achieve.

**If you want to expose custom fields under dc schema**

You simply have to add, in the XSL, blocks similar to the ones that are already present. E.g. you want to expose the content of your custom.test field into dc:description, you can add:

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='custom']/doc:element[@name='test']/doc:element/doc:field[@name='value']">
    <dc:description><xsl:value-of select="." /></dc:description>
</xsl:for-each>
```

**If you want to expose custom fields under custom schema**

You can do exactly the same, but by replacing the dc:description tag with your custom schema:element. You'll need to declare that custom schema in the main `<oai_dc:dc>` tag under `xmlns`:

```
<oai_dc:dc xmlns:oai_dc="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/" 
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
    xmlns:custom="SOME_URL" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc/ http://www.openarchives.org/OAI/2.0/oai_dc.xsd">
```

then

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc:metadata/doc:element[@name='custom']/doc:element[@name='test']/doc:element/doc:field[@name='value']">
                <custom:test><xsl:value-of select="." /></custom:test>
        </xsl:for-each>
</oai_dc:dc>
```

*Note: although this works from a technical point of view, it might however be conflicting with some functional recommendations / business best practices.*